# How to create fluid layout using Bootstrap and LESS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

How to create fluid layout using Bootstrap and LESS without writing code like this:

```
<div class="span12">
```

I try to create LESS code and write this:

```
@import "bootstrap";

div#wrap {
  .container-fluid;
}
header {
  #grid > .fluid > .row-fluid;
}
div#logo {
  #grid > .fluid > .span(2);
}
nav {
  #grid > .fluid > .span(10);
}
```

but this don't work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `makeRow()` and `makeColumn` ?
You can use them like that :

```
header {
  makeRow();
}
div#logo {
  makeColumn(2);
}
nav {
  makeColumn(10);
}
```

Here is a great article explaining why and how to use Bootstrap mixins in LESS : [link](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html)